# eclipse and tomcat debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

While trying to configure eclipse, tomcat to debug a maven project I am getting the following error:

Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused

What am i doing wrong?

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService$2.run(SocketTransportService.java:136)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: Look in the eclipse error log (Window > Show view > Error log) if there's more details about your error. Then checked your tomcat log to see if it's started and listening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'm getting the following from eclispe - updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically means eclipse can't connect to the target tomcat. This may be due to tons of reasons:

- tomcat isn't started
- tomcat isn't accessible over the network
- the debug port is not accessible (check firewall)
- tomcat isn't configured to accept debugging (it should have something like the following in the startup script `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`)